# Overflow X problem with the responsive design in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, responsive

I can't find why i have an overflow on mobile phone (Android and iphone).
I don't have any problem when i use the mobile mode in WordPress.
Someone can help me please?
Here the link : https://nicolas-paysage.fr
Thanks.
frymde

Comment: You have problem with p class="site-description" :) Hide it or change position.

Comment: Thanks. I will look this problem.
But the main problem is resolved.
Thanks to shayan yousefi just below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Add This To Your CSS :

```
html{
overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks a lot !!
It almost work.
I write overflow-x and not overflow.
Because otherwise, I no longer have a vertical scroll 
Thanks again :)

Comment: Oh ! Thanks For Pointing Me To Edit This :)